# Smooth quadrics as quotient of $SO(2n+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I've just started studying parabolic subgroup, and I read I can obtain smooth quadrics of the form
$$x_0x_{n+1}+\ldots+x_{n-1}x_{2n}+x_n^2=0$$
in $\mathbb{P}^{2n}$ as quotients of $SO(2n+1)$ by a appropriate parabolic subgroup, that is a subgroup containing a Borel subgroup.

I know $SO(2n+1)=\{A\in M_{2n+1}(\mathbb{C})\mid A^t Q A=Q \text{ and } \det(A)=1\}$, where
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0_{n,n} & 0 & I_n \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ I_n & 0 & 0_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix},$$

but to be honest I cannot go much further, I always struggle to translate the theory regarding algebraic groups in a concrete example. Since this is very new to me I'd like to understand why this statement is true and how to find such a subgroup: also a proper reference may be fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not the conventional definition of $SO(2n+1)$

Comment: It might be helpful to note that your equation can be written in the form $x^TQx = 0$, with $x$ a length $2n+1$ column-vector.

Comment: Dear @BenGrossmann, first of all thanks for the reply! I know this is not the common definition of the special orthogonal group, but this was the one we used in class. Moreover, yes I've noticed your remark, thus our smooth quadric (let us call $C$) is defined as $C=\{p\in\mathbb{P}^{2n}\mid p^tQp=0\}$

Comment: Moreover, I also know that a Borel subgroup of $SO(2n+1)$ is of the form $0$ everywhere expect $t_1,\ldots,t_n,1,t_1^{-1},\ldots,t_n^{-1}$ on the diaognal, hence a parabolic subgroup must contain this kind of matrices

Comment: I don't see any obvious way forward either, now that I've given it some thought. It is perhaps useful to note that $C$ is invariant under the action of $SO(2n+1)$, as is every "level set" $\{p  \mid p^TQp = k\}$ with $k \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: So I have an action of $SO(2n+1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^{2n}$, couldn't I just consider a point in quadric like $[1:0:\ldots:0]$ and define the quadric as the quotient $SO(2n+1)/SO(2n+1)_p$? May it work?
(I will not be able to respond in the next hours, thanks anyway a lot for the support, hope someomen will come up with a solution)

Comment: It certainly makes intuitive sense that $SO(2n+1)/SO(2n+1)_p$ should give us something "isomorphic" to the orbit of that point $p$, so maybe. That said, I'm a bit weak in this area, so finding a definitive answer will probably be someone else's job.

Comment: I'm not sure why I doubted it in retrospect. [This argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98653/81360) is sufficient.

Comment: So I consider the action of $SO(2n+1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^{2n}$, I pick an element $x_0$ (say $[1:0:\ldots.0]$), then I have that $SO(2n+1)/SO(2n+1)_{x_0}\simeq SO(2n+1)\cdot x_0 \simeq C$... but how can I shoe the orbit of the point is precisely $C$?

Comment: (if you want to spend some minutes writing an answer I'll surely accept it btw!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial Answer:**

To reiterate the ideas from the comments: we note that the set $C = \{p \in \Bbb P^{2n} : p^TQp = 0\}$ is invariant under the action of $SO(2n + 1)$. If we can show that $C$ is the orbit of the point $p = [1:0:\cdots:0]$ under $SO(2n+1)$, then [it follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98653/81360) that our desired quadric is homeomorphic to the quotient $SO(2n+1)/SO(2n+1)_p$.

Equivalently, we want to show the following: for any $x \in \Bbb P^{2n}$ with $x^TQx = 0$, there exists an $A \in SO(2n+1)$ with $Ap = x$.  That is, we need an $A$ whose first column is $x$.

An idea for an indirect approach: I claim that there exists a size $2n+1$ square matrix $F$ such that $A \in SO(2n + 1)$ iff $B = FAF^{-1}$ satisfies $B^TB = I, \det(B) = 1$. With that established, it suffices to show that there is a matrix $B$ with $B(Fp) = B(Fx)$ and $B^TB = I$.